# Adding different cryptocurrencies and intervals to 1 big dataframe or seperate dataframes (issue with NaN values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cryptocurrency

I'm gonna ask a very long and difficult question here, so I'm going to try to explain this as best as possible. So my goal is: I for example want information about Bitcoin and Ethereum. I want the high, low and close prices from both these coins. So first I want these prices from bitcoin. So what I want is: I first have to take 5 times the historical data from these prices and then add the incoming new data from these prices. So for example if my interval is 1minute, I take 5 prices from the previous 5 minutes(historical data) and then every minute I add the new data. So after 5 minutes of waiting I have 10 data values (5 historic, 5 new). This is all very possible with just 1 coin and 1 interval. Whenever I try multiple intervals or multiple coins, it becomes very hard to add the right new data to the right historical data. My try was to append all the values to 1 very big dataframe. So I could later search on for example BTCUSDT/1h (interval) but when I append all these different dataframes to 1 big one, I get a lot of NaN values. I need to get rid of them but I feel like I'm doing the adding to 1 big dataframe incorrect. It makes a new dataframe everytime it runs through the loop, so I actually wanted to store the dataframe it makes every loop to a new dataframe, but I really don't know how to do this. Thats why I kept appending it to a first empty dataframe, and update the empty dataframe everytime. So the main question is: How do I make a new dataframe from the values everytime it loops, OR how do I append it correctly to the big dataframe without getting all these NaN values. I hope this is a bit clear and I'll put my relevant code below here and I hope someone can help me figure this out, Thanks!

```
symbols = ['ETHUSDT','BTCUSDT']
intervals = ['30m','1h']

api_secret = ***
api_key = ***
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

dic = {}
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()
for interval in intervals:
    for symbol in symbols:
        historical = client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, '11/16/2021', limit=1000)[-4:]
        df = pd.DataFrame(historical)
        df.drop([6,7,8,9,10,11], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.columns = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        form = {(symbol, interval, 'time'): df['time'], (symbol, interval,'open'): df['open'], \
               (symbol, interval, 'high'): df['high'], (symbol, interval,'low'): df['low'], \
               (symbol, interval, 'close'): df['close'], (symbol, interval,'volume'): df['volume']}
        df2 = empty_df.append(pd.DataFrame(form))
        empty_df = df2



[![Dataframe!][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBIAa.png
ps: SAW ERROR IN CODE WHICH MADE BTC AND ETH GIVE SAME VALUES, FIXED IT IN CODE BUT NOT PICTURE. PROBLEM STAYS THE SAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse I find the answer just after posting the question!
Here it is for everyone wondering:
instead of adding a dataframe every loop to an empty dataframe, you simply append the dataframes to a list and concat the dataframes in that list after the loop.

example:

```
lst = []
for interval in intervals:
    for symbol in symbols:
        historical = client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', interval, '11/16/2021', limit=1000)[-4:]
        df = pd.DataFrame(historical)
        df.drop([6,7,8,9,10,11], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.columns = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        form = {(symbol, interval, 'time'): df['time'], (symbol, interval,'open'): df['open'], \
               (symbol, interval, 'high'): df['high'], (symbol, interval,'low'): df['low'], \
               (symbol, interval, 'close'): df['close'], (symbol, interval,'volume'): df['volume']}
        lst.append(pd.DataFrame(form))
        
lst = pd.concat(lst, axis=1)
```